# How can I set time for consumer side in RABBITMQ

Tags: java, xml, multithreading, string, rabbitmq

This is my code and i set the true on autoDelete both queue , exchange finally publish is not sending any message to consumer several minute at this time i would like stop the consumer side automatically maybe you are not understand my sentence perfectly.

how can i setting that ^^

and how do I get document Object(doc) in server side

```
 public void initConsumer() {
  try {
   ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
   Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
   Channel channel = connection.createChannel();
   channel.queueDeclare(this.queueName, this.maintain, false, this.queueAutoDelete, null);
   channel.exchangeDeclare(this.exchangeName, this.exchangeType, this.maintain, this.exchangeAutoDelete, null);
    channel.queueBind(this.queueName, this.exchangeName, this.routingKey);
    QueueingConsumer consumer = new QueueingConsumer(channel);
   channel.basicConsume(this.queueName, false, consumer);
   while (true) {

    QueueingConsumer.Delivery delivery = consumer.nextDelivery();

    System.out.println(" [x] Received "
      + new String(delivery.getBody()));

    channel
      .basicAck(delivery.getEnvelope().getDeliveryTag(),
        false);
    }
  } catch (Exception e) {
   System.out.println("Exception error at initConsumer()");
  }
 }
```

Comment: I think what you're asking is, "How can I have my Consumer shut down automatically if it does not receive any messages from the broker in several minutes?" Is that correct?

Comment: yes doesn't receive any message from the broker.

Comment: at that time i want stop the comsumer side. and set the watting time.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the overloaded version of nextDelivery() which has a timeout parameter:

```
QueueingConsumer.Delivery delivery = null;
long timeout = 2 * 60 * 1000; // 2 minutes in milliseconds
delivery = queuingConsumer.nextDelivery(timeout);
if (delivery == null) {
  // shut down your consumer here - no events arrived
  // before the timeout was reached
}
else {
  // process the delivered message here
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: @BrianKelly: setting timeout to zero means receive with no waiting?

Comment: @BrianKelly, QueuingConsumer is deprecated now. How can we apply a timeout to DefaultConsumer? Thanks.